# No power at dash

Tags: subaru, impreza, no-crank-no-start

I have a 1993 Subaru Impreza L 1.8 L. I have no power at dash and a couple of days ago I went to go start the car and it wasn't attempting to turn over. I had full power at dash and everywhere else, but I didn't hear the starter making contact so I obviously assumed it was the starter. I replaced that, but still had the same thing: no power.  The starter's still not attempting to turn over, so I went back and replaced the ignition switch but now I have no power anywhere in the dash and no power at all in the entire car.  Even the locks won't work now. Any thoughts?

I checked the battery and it was reading 3.9 so I tried jumping it and the same thing happened and as for putting in the old ignition switch and checking the fuseible link. It looks fine - no burns or anything.

Comment: Have you got a good battery?  A volt meter should read 12.5V or so across the terminals.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! First, put your original ignition switch back in. Second, check to ensure your fusible link in the under hood fuse box is still viable. It should be locate at the forward most portion of the fuse box. The ones I've seen look like a thick-ish wire with a white covering.